# A tool to convert JSON to C struct?

Tags: c, json, metaprogramming

I'm just wondering if anyone has already created a tool that will take a given JSON string and write the code for an identical struct in C along with the parser code specific to that struct.

I'm about to do this myself using JSON-C, but I thought I'd ask first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `protobuf` is my best bet. A guy on the NodeJS list led me on to this.

- [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/)
- [node-protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-for-node/)
- [protobuf-js](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-js/)